# Is there a terminal that features sliding like guake and screen spliting like terminator on Linux?

Tags: terminal, split-window

Sliding means I got the terminal always in background and I can call it with a shortcut, and it will slide down from the top of the screen like in Quake (which why the most known terminal implementing it is called [guake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHrIXQNY8VE)).

Splitting terminal means I can seen in one terminal tab several shells, like with screen or tmux. But I can also take the focus on each part of the terminal by clicking on it, not just with a 4 keys keyboard shortcut. Which [terminator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_U2Yy5B2ASU) let me do.

Is there a terminal that features both on Linux ? Even something I can pay for.

Comment: I [answer here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355145/209677) about using Guake+Byobu+tmux on a very similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yakuake, although it's KDE-based.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: How does it not? Yakuake is a drop-down terminal like guake, can be split, these can be navigated by mouse or keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Then you should be careful to explain it or provide a screen shot least for it. :)

Comment: I accept it since it answers the question perfectly, although after testing this software, the ergonomics is terrible. Plus as you said it's KDE which prevents it to integrate anywhere else properly. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @avirk Well, the question had certain requirements, which yakuake fulfilled. So I didn't think I should have to repeat the requirements listed by the question! I agree that a screenshot would have been nice, but I didn't have time to provide one, so I thought an adequate answer was better than none at all.

Comment: @e-satis I'm using KDE and I just changed back to guake, to be honest (but only so I could swap the keyboard shortcuts for Copy and Sigint). I never had issues with the ergonomics though… what do you mean by that?

Comment: The way thinks are layed out, their size, their color, their position, the icons. They are very confusing.

Comment: @e-satis Fair points. I'm probably used to the lay-out and position from KDE, and the color and (some) icons are probably configurable from the KDE system settings (but admittedly does require more tweaking if you are using Gnome). I actually find yakuake much prettier than guake at least, but to each their own. :)

Answer (score 2):

Now Terminator itself natively supports Guake like functionality.

Refer to the following article.

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/install-terminator-with-built-in-quake.html

The article is quite old, and claims that the Guake like functionality is not there in the release candidate. But, the feature has now been included. All the other info relating to setting up the feature in Terminator are still relevant.